# Lotus Notes 8.5.3 crashes on startup as normal user but not as admin

Tags: windows-7, crash, lotus-notes

I have a really interesting problem here with Lotus Notes 8.5.3:

When I start Lotus Notes in single user mode as Admin on my Windows 7 64-bit client, I can run the Lotus Notes initial setup (where I have to provide my name, etc.).

If I do start Lotus Notes without administrator permissions, it immediately crashes and the LOG-collection tool (NSD?) pops up. But in the generated NSD files, there is nothing - the last line even states that there is no error to report.

Well, what can I do from here on? I've been cleaning my notes.ini and also my data path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I messed around a bit more and came to the following solution:

Somehow the user permissions of the data-folder got screwed. Thus, just cleaning this directory did not solve my problem. Anyway, granting permissions to the user again, the problem is fixed. This can be done with

```
    icacls.exe <path>/Data /grant <user>:(CI)(OI)F
```

In my eyes this is clearly a software bug, as Lotus Notes should warn the user about missing permissions on the data location.

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you install it in "multi-user" mode normally then the data directory goes into the user profile rather than under program files(x86) etc. path.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)